# Assigning non-ASCII characters to wide char and printing with printf

Tags: c, utf-8, ascii, locale, wchar-t

How can I assign non-ASCII characters to a wide char and print it to the console? This code down doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    wchar_t wc = L'ć';
    printf("%lc\n", wc);
    printf("%ld\n", wc);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
263
Press [Enter] to close the terminal ...
```

I'm using MinGW GCC on Windows 7.

Comment: you're not assigning it to a char, you're assigning it to a wchar_t

Comment: [`wchar_t` is not ASCII.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)

Comment: how to assignt character 'ć' to any char, int, variable and print it correct? IS it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your calls to `printf()` fail with an «Illegal byte sequence» error returned in `errno`, at least that is what happens here on MacOS X with the above example code (and also if using `wprintf()` instead of `printf()`).  For me it works when I call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` before the call to `printf()` so that it stops using the C locale by default:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(void)
{
    wchar_t wc = L'ć';

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("%lc\n", wc);

    return 0;
}
```

It is unclear what platform/compiler you are on, so YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`wprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) to print wide-character strings:

```
wprintf(L"%c\n", wc);
```

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't print any character

Comment: @balky - then the console you're using doesn't display wide characters correctly

Comment: you mean windows console window?I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

use wprintf("%lc\n" ,wc);    and you will get your desired output

Comment: what output u really want ?