# Resprent chinese character in c

Tags: c, unicode

i want to represent hex code 0x4E00 to chinese character in c. With ASCII represent hex code 0x41, it will become 'a' character.

```
int a = 0x41;
printf("%c--%d",a,a); // A---65

int b = 0x4E00;
printf("%c--%",b,b); // --11776
```

So how can represent chex code chinese character like ASCII charater.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206490/assigning-non-ascii-characters-to-wide-char-and-printing-with-printf) it shows how to print `wide character`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [wprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wprintf/). Also you need to set the locale as:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```